# Plugin manager screen is not working, unable to add Parallel Controller plugin for jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Plugin manager screen is not working, unable to add Parallel Controller plugin for jmeter.

I have added `jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar` in `lib/ext` folder and jmeter restarted properly. Still jmeter plugin manager screen showing error as below.

```
Failed to download plugins repository. One of the possible reasons is that you have proxy requirement for Internet connection.
Please read the instructions on this page: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/  Error's technical details:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
```

I made all the necessary configuration mentioned on add plugin manager. I have found similar problem solution on stack overflow but I didn't get it and also it is not working.

Please help me on this with proper solution.

[Plugin manager on adding Jar in lib/ext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJs05.png)

[Error on plugin Manager screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDQcO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Parallel Sampler and Controller manually

1. Download https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/bzm-parallel-0.7.zip (or whatever is the latest version) is available at [JMeter Plugins Catalog](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) page

   [image: JMeter Plugins Download Manually]
2. Unpack the archive and copy `jmeter-parallel-0.7.jar` to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter to pick up the plugin

More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Comment: Parallel controller added sucessfully but How can I map my HTTP request sampler in bzm-prallelController to jp@gc - Parallel HTTP Requests. As Parallel http request configurations are not understandable. Please help on this.

Comment: My Scenario is 
1.Connection request to API
2.Send/upload 4 files at every connection
  (bunch of 4 upload http POST request multiple times )